# how to change the scale of the x-axis so that the orange and blue graphs are displayed correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I cannot correctly depict two graphs: orange and blue. I've read the documentation, tried changing the values until nothing comes out.
How to show these graphs, as in 1 picture, together with others correctly

[image]

I get it like this

[image]

My code
My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



x = np.array([0.264, 0.331, 0.397, 0.417, 0.438, 0.45, 0.459, 0.466])
y = np.array([0.01, 0.1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
# creating scatter plot with both negative
# and positive axes
plt.plot(x, y, marker='o')
x = np.array([0.375, 0.435, 0.494, 0.512, 0.53, 0.541, 0.548, 0.564])
y = np.array([0.01, 0.1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
plt.plot(x, y, marker='o')
x2points=np.array([-3.672, -3.733, -3.793, -3.811, -3.828, -3.839, -3.846, -3.852])
y2points = np.array([-0.01, -0.1, -1, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10])
plt.plot(x2points, y2points, marker = 'o')
x2points = np.array([-14.86, -14.931, -14.998, -15.018, -15.039, -15.051, -15.06, -15.067])
y2points = np.array([-0.01, -0.1, -1, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10])
plt.plot(x2points, y2points, marker='o')
# adding vertical line in data co-ordinates
plt.axvline(0, c='black', ls='--')

# adding horizontal line in data co-ordinates
plt.axhline(0, c='black', ls='--')
plt.xticks([-15,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1])
plt.yticks([-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

# visualizing the plot using plt.show() function
plt.show()
```

The result I want to get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuD8C.jpg)

Comment: please provide your code as text, not images

Comment: what exactly is your problem? If you comment the bottom part of your code (starting from `x2points`), you'll get the top graph. Of course, if you have very different x values, the data will be compressed to display all on a limited width. Eventually provide a schematic of what you expect

Comment: Is it possible to prevent blocking of orange and blue charts?

Comment: What does "blocking" mean? Can you provide a schematic?

Comment: Can the orange and blue charts be prevented from squeezing?

Comment: Simple answer: no, this is not mathematically possible. But maybe I don't understand what you want, in which case you need to provide a schematic.

Comment: It's a matter of scale, as I understand it. I want to make the graphs appear as in 1 picture.

Comment: I ask one final time then I give up: **please provide a schematic of what you envision** (hand drawn is fine)

Comment: I apologize for the incorrectness of the question due to the translation. This is how I want to display the graphs as opposed to the original drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red and green curve use an x-range from -15 to -4, while the orange and blue curves have a very limited range between 0.25 and 0.55. Displaying them together on the same graph will necessarily lead to the compression you see.

You can draw two subplots, and move them close together while sharing the y-axis.  That way, different x-axes can be used:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15, 4), sharey=True,
                               gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0})

x = np.array([0.264, 0.331, 0.397, 0.417, 0.438, 0.45, 0.459, 0.466])
y = np.array([0.01, 0.1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
# creating scatter plot with both negative
# and positive axes
ax2.plot(x, y, marker='o')
x = np.array([0.375, 0.435, 0.494, 0.512, 0.53, 0.541, 0.548, 0.564])
y = np.array([0.01, 0.1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
ax2.plot(x, y, marker='o')

x2points = np.array([-3.672, -3.733, -3.793, -3.811, -3.828, -3.839, -3.846, -3.852])
y2points = np.array([-0.01, -0.1, -1, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10])
ax1.plot([], [])  # 2 dummy plots to move the color cycle
ax1.plot([], [])
ax1.plot(x2points, y2points, marker='o')
x2points = np.array([-14.86, -14.931, -14.998, -15.018, -15.039, -15.051, -15.06, -15.067])
y2points = np.array([-0.01, -0.1, -1, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10])
ax1.plot(x2points, y2points, marker='o')
# adding vertical line in data co-ordinates
# plt.axvline(0, c='black', ls='--')

# adding horizontal line in data co-ordinates
ax1.axhline(0, c='black', ls='--')
ax2.axhline(0, c='black', ls='--')
# set ticks and data limiits
ax1.set_xticks(range(-15, 0))
ax1.set_xlim(xmax=0)
ax1.set_yticks(range(-10, 11))
ax2.set_xlim(xmin=0)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: two plots close together, sharing the y-axis]